# Detect decimal separator

Tags: c#, globalization

I have to detect decimal separator in current windows setting. Im using visual studio 2010, windows form. In particular, if DecimalSeparator is comma, if user input dot in textbox1,  I need show zero in textbox2.

I tryed with this code, but not works:

```
private void tbxDaConvertire_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        string uiSep = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
        if (uiSep.Equals(","))
        {
            while (e.KeyChar == (char)46)
            {
                tbxConvertito.Text = "0";
            }
        } 
    }
```

I have tryed also this code, but not work:

```
private void tbxDaConvertire_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        string uiSep = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
        if (uiSep.Equals(","))
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)46)
            {
                tbxConvertito.Text = "0";
            }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: "but not works" doesn't tell us what went wrong.

Comment: Since we can't read your mind or see your screen from here, it would be really useful if you included an explanation of what "not works" means.

Comment: Sorry Ken, I mean that with this code, if I put dot in textbox1, textbox2 not change content (not show zero). Sorry my bad english

Comment: vincenzolopalo your code makes no sense if you put a `"."` in the text box this should be allowed since is a normal decimal separator are you saying that if they enter a comma that you don't want that..? if so that's incorrect too.. what if someone enters the number `1,000,001.50` ..? please try to show and or explain your example of what you are looking for better..

Comment: I mean.... If I put dot where decimalSeparator is comma

Comment: Vincenzolopalo, for starters you do not need a while loop second you need to explain what you want better.. are you saying that you do not want to allow "," also when checking `==` vs `.Equals` you should know when to use one over the other normally when comparing Objects the `.Equals` would work.. either way.. your current logic is flawed why don't you use a Masked Edit instead..?

Comment: example: in my computer separator decimal is comma. In my application, if I put 1500.00 in textbox, this number has no sense. Than, I need prevent this scenario

Comment: to solve your issue just use a [MaskedTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx) `<==click here` to learn more about it

Comment: the number makes sense it's telling me 1500.00 are you trying to represent Currency..? you can get around that issue as well

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Solution:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    char a = Convert.ToChar(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator);
    if (e.KeyChar == a)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        textBox1.Text = "0";
    }
}
```

That way, when you hit `.` or `,` you will have a `0` in your TextBox.

EDIT:

If you want to insert a `0` everytime you hit the decimal separator, this is the code:

```
char a = Convert.ToChar(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator);
if (e.KeyChar == a)
{
    e.KeyChar = '0';
}
```

Comment: If you need a textbox where the user can input only numbers I have the code.. MaskedTextboxes are a solution too, but I don´t like them.

Comment: thanks Andres, this is really solution that I need!! :) But work perfectly with this: CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator

Comment: Sure! Glad to help you out :)

Answer (score 45):

Actually you should be using

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator
```

instead of

```
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator
```

Using the second one gives you the OS default settings, which might be different then user Regional Locales for particular user account logged to this PC.

Credits to [berhir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2929675/berhir) and [Grimm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9071626/grimm) for pointing out the [[docs]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: I don't think this is correct. This is what the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?view=netcore-3.1) say:
`The current culture is a property of the executing thread. Retrieving the value of the CultureInfo.CurrentCulture property is a more performant equivalent of retrieving the CultureInfo object returned by the Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture property.`

Comment: berhir is right.  The docs clearly recommend to use CultureInfo: `The current culture is a property of the executing thread. When you set this property to a CultureInfo object that represents a new culture, the value of the Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture property also changes. However, we recommend that you always use the CultureInfo.CurrentCulture property to retrieve and set the current culture.`

Comment: It was some time ago but I think what I've ment was not to use CurrentUICulture (with UI inside). But I agree you have found more performant way to do so. Thank you for spotting this.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use a `while` loop, I think it will freeze the application, use `if` instead, the problem might be here

Comment: where is the changed code..? looks the same in your original question

Comment: are you sure that 46 is the dot code? You could also try this test: `e.KeyChar == '.'`

Comment: ppetrov that does = `"."` test it this way you will see `var somChar = (char)46`

Comment: I believe you @DJ KRAZE, just didn't tested it and thought this way there can't be any error with the char code. but as you said it in a previous comment, the main problem with the code was the `.Equals`

Comment: not a problem pptrov.. but his initial problem lies within a few things ..1 using a While loop which he does not need, checking for "," which he will never find because he needs to check the Key , 3rd using the incorrect Control, he should use a MaskedEdit instead