# String formatting combine N2 and decimal

Tags: c#, string, formatting, decimal

I have decimals values and want to show them without values after the decimal point. For example

> 10.00 => 10.

I already have **N2** formatting.

```
myValue.ToString("N2");
```

Is there a simple way to *combine* those two?

Comment: you need `ToString("N0")`. Note that it will **ROUND** the number as well.

Comment: I doubt that the tag N2 fits this quesion. Look into its description. Seems your question does not havy anything to do with a CMS.

Comment: Thanks tchelidze, it worked perfectly

Answer (score 3):

You can use a 0 placeholder followed by a period literal inserted into the format string. To insert a literal, escape it with a backslash. Note that a single backslash is already an escape for string literals, so you actually need two, or you can use a [verbatim string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311988/what-is-the-difference-between-a-regular-string-and-a-verbatim-string), as in this example:

```
var d = 10.00M;
Console.WriteLine( d.ToString(@"0\.") );  //Outputs "10."
```

If you are worried about internationalization, don't use a period constant; use a decimal separator [from the current culture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14513468/detect-decimal-separator).

```
string decimalSymbol = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
Console.WriteLine( d.ToString(@"\" + decimalSymbol) );  //Outputs "10." or "10,"
```

Comment: ... nice detail with the `.`

Comment: Does this work in countries where `.` is _not_ the decimal separator?

Comment: @UweKeim It will output a `.` regardless of locale.