# Why does my float variable is not taking the correct value from the textbox?

Tags: c#

I need to calculate the percent but when I put a float value in the textbox the variable convert the value to an int value.

[image: Results]

```
 float intereses = 0, monto = 0, total = 0;

 intereses = float.Parse(textBox1.Text);
 monto = float.Parse(txtMonto.Text);

 total = ((monto * intereses)/100);

 MessageBox.Show("El "+textBox1.Text+" % de "+monto+" es "+ total);
```

Comment: [Check decimal separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14513468/detect-decimal-separator) and make sure it is set to a '.', currently it is (probably) set to a ',' that's why `0.5` is not being parsed correctly

Comment: What UI framework are you using?

Comment: I´m using Visual Studio 2013 and DevExpress

Comment: see, for an example which should be helpful: https://onlinegdb.com/-H1NY2X_3, click on `Run`, and check the results.....

Answer (score 1):

First, that's not necessary initialize variables in the first line.

If i'm not wrong, For the problem, maybe your UI framework(DevExpress) or windows form component cannot recognize `"."` character in the `textbox` when you're trying to `convert(.Parse)` or validate it to `float type`.

> total = ((5000* 05)/100); Debug: 250

And why you didn't try to put `intereses` in `MessageBox.Show("El "+textBox1.Text+" % de "+monto+" es "+ total);` instead of `textBox1.Text` to see what's the exact problem?

Comment: Thank you , I have solved, I was parsing bad.

Comment: Glad to hear ...

Answer (score 0):

Use the built in `NumericUpDown` control and set the number of decimal places in it as shown below. This control is designed to handle numeric values with or without decimal point, it will handle the decimal point for you so that you don't have to worry about it

[image]

Comment: thank you, I didn´t know that about the numericUpDown